# Extended Kalman Filter practical application

Tags: kalman-filter

I have navigation data to which I need to apply the Extended Kalman Filter in order to predict the next state of a vessel. I have the longitude, latitude (converted to ECEF format) and velocity components, which give me a 4-dimensional state vector. Could someone give me an example of how to proceed with the algorithm given these two records?

```
X: 5011994.26118927, Y: 1301822.70291405, velX: 5.9239649831152805, velY: 5.524186716506238
X: 5011798.8964813, Y: 1302241.63938337, velX: 6.037676641782175, velY: 5.248472231924059
```

Comment: Why not a state with a x and y velocity component (assuming that the speed is the magnitude of the velocity)? Since you want to use an extended Kalman filter do you also have a model?

Comment: Hi @KwinvanderVeen, thank you for your answer, I updated my question to include the velocity components. I do have a problem with writing down the model. I know that the EKF uses these two non-linear equations: _x(k) = f(x(k-1),u(k-1),w(k-1))_ and _z(k)=h(x(k),v(k))_, where _w(k)_ and _v(k)_ represent the process and measurement noise. The non-linear function _f_ should relate the step _x(k)_ to the previous time step _x(k-1)_ and the non-linear function _h_ should relate the state _x(k)_ to the measurement _z(k)_ , but how do I choose these functions?

Comment: Assuming that you have some data already, then you can try to fit a model onto it. Maybe your system behaves linear and time invariant, in which case you can use a normal Kalman filter.